# Access Unity Log Stacktrace when highlighting a Log?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, console, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

When I select any item from the console Log, is there any way to get access to the information is displaying? I'm interested in accessing the information as a string, is it possible?

I mean that piece of information text that appears under the console with information from the selected item. Also would be great if there was an event like `ChangedSelection` but I'd be fine with just the information below. [image]
**Thank you!**

Comment: Well you could use the methods you mentioned but read it into a class that only holds the last x items.

Comment: What's your worry about reading the log file? It's being written to anyway.

Comment: I want to be able to handle them as strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console does not have any selection event as far as i'm aware of. If you're interested in the logs however you can get all logs by using the [Application.logMessageReceived](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-logMessageReceived.html) event. This includes the log message and the stacktrace.

```
void OnEnable()
{
    Application.logMessageReceived += HandleLog;
}

void OnDisable()
{
    Application.logMessageReceived -= HandleLog;
}

void HandleLog(string logString, string stackTrace, LogType type)
{
    output = logString;
    stack = stackTrace;
}
```